# Выдает ошибку Notice: Undefined variable: lang in \MyPhone\index.php on line 83

Tags: php

```
config.php:

<?php
    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['lang']))
        $_SESSION['lang'] = "sk";
    else if (isset($_GET['lang']) && $_SESSION['lang'] != $_GET['lang'] && !empty($_GET['lang'])) {
        if ($_GET['lang'] == "sk")
            $_SESSION['lang'] = "sk";
        else if ($_GET['lang'] == "en")
            $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
    }
?>

insex.php:
    <!doctype html>
    <html class="no-js" lang="sk">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#primary-menu">
    ...
    ...
    <div class="language-header" id="primaty-manu">
    <a href = "index.php?lang=sk"><?php echo $lang['lang_sk'] ?></a> <-В этом месте ошибка
    <a href = "index.php?lang=en">| <?php echo $lang['lang_en'] ?></a> <-В этом месте ошибка
    </div>
    </nav>
    </div>
    </div>

    <header class="header-area overlay full-height relative v-center" id="home page">
    <div class="absolute anlge-bg"></div>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row v-center">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7 header-text">
                 <h2><?php echo $lang['Moj telephon'] ?></h2> <- В этом месте ошибка
      <p>Hcem odporucat vlastnii telephon pre ludi ktoryi nemozu rozhodnut, aky lepsy pre nych.</p>
    </div>
        </header>
    ....
</html>
```

Comment: `Notice` Это не ошибка а предупреждение чтоль, вобщем переменная `lang` не обьявлена на момент попытки использовать ее значение. и происходит это в строке номер 83

Comment: А прогуглить сложно, прежде чем вопрос сюда писать?